# Separating values into dictionaries and counting them in Python

Tags: python

I’m trying to take a list of numbers, separate the values into dictionaries based on the `int` and `float` types, and then count the number of their occurrences. I’m having issues with the logic.

With the ideal output looking like so:

```
'int' : [1 : 3, 2 : 4, 5 : 1, 6 : 2],
'float' : [1.0 : 2, 2.3 : 4, 3.4 : 4]
```

This is what I have so far, and I keep pounding my head:

```py
values = [1, 2.0, 3.0, 1, 1, 3, 4.0, 2, 1.0]

types = {
    'int': [],
    'float': []
}
for obj in values:
      if isinstance(obj, int):
          types['int'].append(obj)
      elif isinstance(obj, float):
        types['float'].append(obj)

for v in types:
    if v not in types['int']:
        counts = 0
    counts[v] += 1
    elif v not in types['float']:
        counts = 0
    counts[v] += 1

print(counts)
```

With the ideal output being:

```
'int' : [1 : 3, 2 : 4, 5 : 1, 6 : 2],
'float' : [1.0 : 2, 2.3 : 4, 3.4 : 4]
```

Comment: This code won't even compile.  the second `elif` has no `if` to go with it because the `counts[v] += 1` above it is at the same level.  Also, you're treating `counts` like a list but also setting it to 0.  That's strange. - I can't really tell what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

First half seems fine, but second half can improve.

try:

```
for k,v in types.items():
    print(k, len(v))
```

Sample input:

```
values = [1.1,2,3.1]
```

Gives this output:

```
int 1
float 2
```

Comment: Yeah...this seems right on.  I suggest adding a sample `values` array and the accompanying output.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

This leverages the `type` function to give you the keys for the resulting array ('int' and 'float') without having to specify those strings.

```py
numbers = [1,1,1,2.1,2.1,2.2, 3,3.1]

def tally_by_type(numbers):
    result = {}
    for v in numbers:
        k = type(v).__name__
        result[k] = result.get(k, {})
        result[k][v] = result[k].get(v,0)
        result[k][v] = result[k][v] + 1
    return result

tally_by_type(numbers)

{'int': {1: 3, 3: 1}, 'float': {2.1: 2, 2.2: 1, 3.1: 1}}
```

Interestingly, this also works if you have strings in there

```py
tally_by_type([1,2,3,3,3,'a','a','b'])
{'int': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3}, 'str': {'a': 2, 'b': 1}}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this:

```
ints={}
floats={}
list=[3.5,27,87.8,1.02,66]
for val in list:
    if isinstance(val,int):
        ints[str(val)]=val
    elif isinstance(val,float):
        floats[str(val)]=val
print("ints dictionary\n",ints,"number of instances",len(ints))
print("floats dictionary\n",floats,"number of instances",len(floats))
```

which prints:

```
ints dictionary
 {'27': 27, '66': 66} number of instances 2
floats dictionary
 {'3.5': 3.5, '87.8': 87.8, '1.02': 1.02} number of instances 3
```

I did not quite get what dictionary keys you want to use though, assumed you don't really need them.

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose to add this answer that is A) a duplicate of the important part of the first answer added 5+ minutes before you, and B) changes all of the OPs code which is less helpful to him considering that a good part of his code worked perfectly well. - On the plus side, your output is nicely formatted :)

Comment: I think the idea is to end up with 'int' : 1 : 2, 2:4, 'floats' : 1.0 : 3, 3.4: 4, etc